# How can I view a polymorphic type in vscode when debugging c++ with gdb?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb, qt-creator

When debugging a polymorphic type in vs code with gdb, the debug pane only shows it as a pointer to the type of the variable, IE the abstract base class.  However when debugging with qtcreator, the correct concrete type is displayed.  How can I get vscode to have a similar debugging experience?

Comment: If you use gdb bare (from the command line) are you able to get the info you want, ig yes then you can adjust the Debug Protocol on the VSC side to do the same

Comment: Try [set print object on](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Print-Settings.html#set-print-object).

Answer (score 0):

In VS code, add the following to the launch configuration you're using (see the `launch.json` file):

```
"setupCommands": [
    {
        "text": "set print object on",
        "description": "enables to identify the actual (derived) type of an object",
        "ignoreFailures": true
    }
]
```

**Background:** This enables GDB's `print object` setting when starting a debug session in VS code. The default value in GDB for this setting is `off`. See [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Print-Settings.html#set-print-object).